# Angular2 Routing: Multiple Components at once

Tags: angular, routes

I have an angular 2 app in which there are sitting two independend functionalities aka components next to each other (let's call them A and B). Now I want to change what lives in Component A via routing. So far so good. That would be a normal scenario in which we would call Component A the app content component.

My problem is I want to be able to also change what's inside component B via routing.

Of course I could now create routes like http://foo.bar/what-lives-in-a/123/what-lives-in-b/abc
But imagine an app where there are hundreds of things that could live in A and dozends of things that could live in B. I think it would be too painful to create all these sub-routes by hand.

So does anyone of you know a good way to tackle that problem?

Comment: Could you please explain what exactly you want with an example?

Comment: Actually I can. Our team wants to create a UI where on the left side we have a view component. Let's say I want to list all customers. On the right side I have an action component where I can perform any action (independent of what I see in the view component). So I could perform a "create Task" action while I look at the customer list. Mind "create task" has nothing to do with customers

Comment: Yes it is possible and very easy.

Comment: Excellent! May I ask what this very easy solution is?

Comment: @Domenic, added the answer, let me know if its a viable solution for you.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want can be achieved with 2 independent router outlets. It makes sense as the components are independent.
So you are, probably, already having the main router outlet which is in the topmost component and is specified like that:
`<router-outlet></router-outlet>`

To specify another one you need to write the following:
`<router-outlet name="forComponentB"></router-outlet>`
After that you will have to add the route for the named router outlet like that:

`,{path: "comp-b-path", outlet: "forComponentB", component: ComponentB}`

So the resulting url will look something like that:
baseurl/comp-a-url(forComponentB:comp-b-path) and you can manage the state of both components independently by changing the main url or the one in parentheses. Note, that you can add parameters to each of the urls, so its very flexible.

Comment: Wow this sounds just like something I was hoping for! Thanks! I have to try it out in the next couple of days

Comment: Hope it will help, let me know if something will not work, will try to help